# Lost disk space after DD

Tags: dd

I've made a typo while doing:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MiB of=/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk conv=notrunc oflag=append count=2048
$ sudo losetup -c /dev/loop0/
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/loop0
```

In first command, so the rest couldn't execute. I'm new to Ubuntu and I don't know what happened to that 2GB's. Apparently they are lost. How can I return them?

Here is my df:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      17996772  12940340   4239864  76% /
udev             1665928         4   1665924   1% /dev
tmpfs             335100       876    334224   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1675496       376   1675120   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1      110697468 102797320   7900148  93% /host
```

While the last one should have 2 GB's more

Comment: *What* typeo did you make?

Comment: "sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1MiB of=/host/ubuntu/disks/root.diskconv=notrunc oflag=append count=2048"

Comment: Then you created a file named /home/ubuntu/disks/root.diskconv=notrunc instead of appending to /home/ubuntu/disks/root.disk.  Just delete that file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please add this as an answer. I will check it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you created a file named `/home/ubuntu/disks/root.diskconv=notrunc` instead of appending to `/home/ubuntu/disks/root.disk`. Just delete that file.